# PickList visibility depends on option set

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a On-Two Option Set having options 1 is for YES and 2 is for NO and there are two pick Lists.

If I say YES, then only first pick List should visible and second one should become invisible and same for opposite. I try to do this but it works for only one time when I select NO after that it remains same independent of what u select.

How to do this???

Comment: Could you precise your code and the language you use?

Comment: var education=Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_education").getValue().toString(); if (education) {
        alert(education + "if");
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("new_postgraduation").setVisible(true);
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("new_graduation").setVisible(false);

        //Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get(1).setVisible(true);
        
    }
    else {
            alert(education+"inside else");
            Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("new_graduation").setVisible(true);
            Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("new_postgraduation").setVisible(false);
            
            
        }

Comment: var education = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_education").getValue().toString();

    if (education) {
        alert(education + "if");
        
        Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("new_postgraduation").setVisible(true);
        Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("new_graduation").setVisible(false);
        
    }
    else {
            alert(education + "inside false");
            Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("new_graduation").setVisible(true);
            Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("new_postgraduation").setVisible(false);
            
           
        }

Comment: Have you registered the JavaScript function on change on the picklist? Code in comments is quite unreadable, rather edit your question.

Comment: Yes I had registered it on change but the problem was in if statement. I found it letter.

Answer (score 0):

Use the onChange event of the picklist, and check your code with the ***Debugging*** keyword and you will find the problem.